# Sending notification , couple of hundred android devices , using FCM

Tags: php, android, notifications

I'm developing an application in PHP which sends a notification to the group( 100 to 500 devices) of  android devices and I have hundreds of these groups.

What would be the right approach here to send a notification?

1. should I use GROUP MESSAGING, which limits the number of members to 20, making multiple groups like for 200 devices 10 GROUP MESSAGING.
2. or USE TOPIC but if I use topic I will have hundreds of topics which is not a big issue for me to handle but my number of members for single notification is only a couple of hundreds ( 100 to 500 devices).
3. or send a message to each devices using registration token which I don't find effective if have to send a large amount of notification .

or is there any better option for sending notifications for my case

or is it possible to send notification in the chunk of 100 devices or 200 effectively using HTTP request

sorry for my poor English. so please advice.

Answer (score 0):

With the following body where `registration_ids` is the array of device tokens I managed to sent push to multiple devices. I don't know whether it can be used to sent up to 500 devices. Give it a try.

```
    {
        "registration_ids":["device_token1","device_token2"],
    "data":{
        "title":"APP NAME",
        "text":" 1 new notification received",
        "category":"SMS",
        "id":"abcdef"
    }
}
```

Comment: registration_id length goes up to 4k byte and sending hundreds of token in one request could take huge space only for token though i will try..